# How to keep TOC visible on side when scrolling down?

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, tableofcontents

I am attempting to use the built-in theme 'sphinxdoc' for my reStructuredText documentation that's being built with Sphinx for deployment on readthedocs.io. This works as I was hoping except for the behavior of the table of contents, which stays at the top when I scroll down, losing visibility. I would like the table of contents to stay visible on the side of the page, as it does for the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/). How can this be done? Is this a layout issue, addressed with CSS, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [built-in themes](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html?highlight=sphinxdoc#builtin-themes):

> Note
>
> The Sphinx documentation now uses [an adjusted version of the sphinxdoc theme](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/doc/_themes/sphinx13).

...which in turn has the [comment](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/doc/_themes/sphinx13/layout.html#L34):

```
// intelligent scrolling of the sidebar content
```

I couldn't find whether the modified theme `sphinx13` could be installed, but you could just grab the code and [override the `sphinxdoc` theme](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html#using-a-theme) with it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I wanted to do this too.

So just for future reference for anyone trying to do this you do not *need* to install the spinx13 theme as mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887934/7858439).

1. You need to add the following to a `layout.html` in the `template` directory

```html
{# put the sidebar before the body #}
{% block sidebar1 %}{{ sidebar() }}{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar2 %}{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
{{ super() }}
{#- if not embedded #}
    <style type="text/css">
      table.right { float: left; margin-left: 20px; }
      table.right td { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
      {% if pagename == 'index' %}
      .related { display: none; }
      {% endif %}
    </style>
    <script>
      // intelligent scrolling of the sidebar content
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sb = $('.sphinxsidebarwrapper');
        var win = $(window);
        var sbh = sb.height();
        var offset = $('.sphinxsidebar').position()['top'];
        var wintop = win.scrollTop();
        var winbot = wintop + win.innerHeight();
        var curtop = sb.position()['top'];
        var curbot = curtop + sbh;
        // does sidebar fit in window?
        if (sbh < win.innerHeight()) {
          // yes: easy case -- always keep at the top
          sb.css('top', $u.min([$u.max([0, wintop - offset - 10]),
                                $(document).height() - sbh - 200]));
        } else {
          // no: only scroll if top/bottom edge of sidebar is at
          // top/bottom edge of window
          if (curtop > wintop && curbot > winbot) {
            sb.css('top', $u.max([wintop - offset - 10, 0]));
          } else if (curtop < wintop && curbot < winbot) {
            sb.css('top', $u.min([winbot - sbh - offset - 20,
                                  $(document).height() - sbh - 200]));
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
{#- endif #}
{% endblock %}
```

2. add a custom css file `mycustom.css` to `_static` (can be named anything.css as long as it is added to the `conf.py` file -- see step 3)

```css
div.sphinxsidebarwrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

div.sphinxsidebar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    width: 210px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

div.sphinxsidebar .logo {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #0A507A;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

div.sphinxsidebar .logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.sphinxsidebar .download a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

3. edit the `conf.py` file:

```py
# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

# add custom css
def setup(app):
   app.add_stylesheet('mycustom.css')  # give a filename you created.
```

That was enough to get it to work with me.

**Note** I was using `html_theme = 'bizstyle'` - I haven't tested this with other themes.

**Note** you may have to adjust the `css` file and `layout.html` to suit your needs.

For more on the layout.html and templating [see here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html).

All this code was taken and modified from [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/doc/_themes/sphinx13)

Comment: [@NeilCook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7858439/neil-cook) I got the scrolling part to work (showing the sidebar always) except for one problem: the sidebar is shown flush in the right 'frame' only on the top page index.html. On any other page, the sidebar overlaps the content window/frame with 80% of sidebar width inside the content window, and the right frame has the remaining 20%. I tried playing with layout.html and css file to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After some searching figured out that `.related{ display: inline-block }` style setting in `layout.html` for all pages does the trick. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) was a great resource in my search.